# Determine how large a buffer should be

Tags: c#, .net, windows, tcp

I am reading from a tcp stream - I have queried an FTP server with the "MLSD" command (retrieve file / directory information). Although since response size is variable (dependent on the amount of files / directory etc.) I am unsure of how many bytes the "buffer" should be set at. How can I make sure all the data is retrieved from the FTP server through the tcp stream?

```
 private string controlListener(int controlPort)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient. 
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
                // combination.
                controlClient = new TcpClient(ftpHost, controlPort);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
                controlStream = controlClient.GetStream();

                    // Because we don't know how many bytes are incoming for welcome message - we use a 2 second delay to retrieve all bytes within that time frame.
                    // Receive the TcpServer.response. 
                    // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                    Byte[] data = new Byte[4096];

                    // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                    String responseData = String.Empty;

                    // Get Control Stream Responce: Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                    Int32 bytes = controlStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                    Console.WriteLine(responseData);

                    return responseData;
            }
```

Comment: The whole point of buffering is that, if you do it properly (you aren't doing it properly), you'll successfully read the whole stream regardless of the buffer size.  The buffer only affect the amount of memory used, and possibly the performance of the application.

Answer (score 4):

In follow-on from Mark's answer...I use this method and you should easily see how to incorporate it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Read TCP response, this simple method can be re-used elsewhere as needed later.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ReadResponse(NetworkStream networkStream)
    {
        // Check to see if this NetworkStream is readable.
        if (networkStream.CanRead)
        {
            var myReadBuffer = new byte[256]; // Buffer to store the response bytes.
            var completeMessage = new StringBuilder();

            // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
            do
            {
                var numberOfBytesRead = networkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                completeMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
            } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

            return completeMessage.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Read/Receive should be used in a loop, reading either until you get an EOF (zero bytes read) or the amount of data you were expecting (of using a framing API). Your current code is not valid: a single byte is a legal amount to return in a single call to Read, even if 483628 bytes were sent.

Answer (score 1):

I use this...

```
        public static byte[] readFullStream(Stream st, Int32 BufferSize)
        {
            try
            {
                Monitor.Enter(_lock);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
                Int32 bytesRead;
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bool finished = false;
                while (!finished)
                {
                    bytesRead = st.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        finished = true;
                    }
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
            finally
            {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
        }
```